# After Linux restart, Kafka throwing "no brokers found when trying to rebalance"

Tags: linux, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I followed an [excellent step-by-step tutorial for installing Kafka on Linux](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-14-04). Everything was working fine for me until I restarted Linux. After the restart, I get the following error when I try to consume a queue with `kafka-console-consumer.sh`.

```
$ ~/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic TutorialTopic --from-beginning
```

> [2016-02-04 03:16:54,944] WARN [console-consumer-6966_bob-kafka-storm-1454577414492-8728ae43], **no brokers found when trying to rebalance**. (kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector)

Before I ran the `kafka-console-consumer.sh` script, I did push data to the Kafka queue using the `kafka-console-producer.sh` script. These steps worked without issue before restarting Linux.

I can fix the error by manually starting Kafka; but, I would rather that Kafka start automatically.

What might cause Kafka to not start correctly after restart?

Answer (score 1):

So I had a similar issue in our hortonworks cluster earlier today. It seems like zookeeper was not starting correctly. I first tried kakfa-console-producer and got the exception below:

````
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list=localhost:9093 --topic=some_topic < /tmp/sometextfile.txt```

kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics```
````

The solution for me was to restart the server that had stopped responding. yours may be different but play around with console producer and see what errors your getting.

Answer (score 1):

I has this same issue today when running a consumer:

`WARN [console-consumer-74006_my-machine.com-1519117041191-ea485191], no brokers found when trying to rebalance. (kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector)`

It turned out to be a disk full issue on the machine.  Once space was freed up, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

By default kafka stores all the information in the `/tmp` folder. The tmp folder gets deleted every time you restart. You can change the placement of those files by changing in the properties file `config/server.properties` the property `log.dirs`.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting everything out relating to zookeeper and kafka out of the /tmp folder.. worked for me. But my system is not production.. so for other people proceed with caution.

Answer (score 0):

For me，when start a consumer to fetch the message from broker cluster. But the Kafka server was shut down.
So, returned the message "no brokers found when trying to rebalance".
When i restart the kafka server, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

For producer consumer to work you have to start a broker. Broker is what intermediates message passing from producer to consumer.

`sh kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh kafka/config/server.properties`

The broker runs on 9092 port by default